# Adding characters to a string in a list Python3

Tags: python, string, list

I was trying to add characters to my list but the compiler threw this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
    arr[i] += 'ma'
```

Here is my full code:

```py
arr = ["Hello", "Hi", "Greetings"]
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

for i in enumerate(arr):
    if [i[1]] in vowels:
        arr[i] += 'ma'
    else:
        arr = list(map(lambda i: i[1:], arr))
        arr[i] += 'ma'
```

I tried to use the enumerate() tag but it still didn't work.

Comment: What is `vowels`?

Comment: enumerate() returns a tuple containing (index, current_element) so enumerating `['a','b','c']` returns `[(0,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'c')]`

Comment: You might also want to just do `for i in range(len(arr))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Daviid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5640517/daviid) said:

> enumerate() returns a tuple containing (index, current_element)...

So, you should consider this in your code:

```py
arr = ["Hello", "Hi", "Greetings"]
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

for i, word in enumerate(arr):
    if word[0].lower() in vowels:
        arr[i] += 'ma'
    else:
        arr[i] = word[1:] + 'ma'
```